# App code in published asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, build

I published my asp.net app using the basic capability (publish to disk). Now I look at the published content and it contains .cs files. Is this correct? I did right-click 'convert to web application', but the .cs files still appear.

Comment: Which publish option did you choose? There are options that can determine which files are pushed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your conversion didn't take or your publish went wrong - according to MSDN:

"The conversion process causes Visual Studio to recursively examine every page, master page, and user control in the project, and to automatically generate a .designer.cs or .designer.vb file for each. Visual Studio also changes the .aspx or .ascx files to use the codeBehind attribute instead of the codeFile attribute. **This conversion process also renames the App_Code folder to Old_App_Code.**"

See:[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx)

So if you see App_Code after conversion - something is screwy and you need to try it again.